# Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

After: npm i firebase

> I'am importing firebase from firebase itself & not from a file

**import firebase from 'firebase';**   >in firebase.js file<

error in terminal>>
**./src/firebase.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\Home\Documents\dsn\e\Documents..........'**

Comment: Try importing firebase using ```import firebase from 'firebase/app';``` and importing the relative [firebase modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) as needed.

Comment: it dosen't work. it' ll say there is no default export in the particular folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you clarify the quoted text (the type of import?)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`npm i firebase` now installs v9 Modular SDK so you cannot used the old imports. Try refactoring your code to this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

If you want to use older syntax then change your imports to compat libraries:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import "firebase/compat/firestore"
// other services is needed
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Comment: I' am already updated to v9 and "firebase/compact/app" do worked for me.✔

Answer (score 2):

There should be no reason to downgrade to version 8 as version 9 provides a fully backward compatible import if you prefix the module import path with "compat".

To use:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
// Other libraries might need to also be prefixed with "compat":
import "firebase/compat/auth";

// Then you can then use the old interface, with version 9:
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials);
}
```

Upgrade notes: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of firebase have many changes, use this ->

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  ....
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
const firebaseApp =firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Use these for db & auth
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { auth, db };
```

Comment: this is working

Answer (score 0):

**initializeApp** is moved to firebase/app package in latetst version
so import from firebase/app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).