# How to use firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() now?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am following a tutorial and firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is used in the code to set `timestamp` prop as the server timestamp.

```
import firebase from "firebase";
```

```
const someFunction = () => {
    addDoc(collection(db, `rooms/${roomId}/messages`), {
      message: input,
      name: user.displayName,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    }).then((res) => getMessagesData());
  };
```

But I get this error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase' in ...
```

I suppose firebase had some kind of update that we don't import it with `import firebase from "firebase";` anymore? What should I do to use the `servertimestamp()`?

Comment: "I am following a tutorial" Can you provide a link please, so that we can check what assumptions the tutorial makes?

Comment: For the actual error message, this has been coming up quite regularly recently since Firebase change the syntax of its JavaScript SDKs in v9. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69044315/module-not-found-cant-resolve-firebase-in

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUxrDcITyjg at 3:07:42. Thanks.

Comment: Given when this tutorial came out, it must be using version 8 or earlier of the SDKJs, which had a different syntax. You will either have to import the same version of the SDK as the tutorial used, or upgrade all code **and** imports as shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade or in the link I gave earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an up to date sample, see the documentation on [adding a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_9), which contains this snippet

```
import { updateDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, 'objects', 'some-id');

// Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
const updateTimestamp = await updateDoc(docRef, {
    timestamp: serverTimestamp()
});
```

The documentation has side-by-side examples for both the new v9 modular syntax and the older syntax that you're likely to find in many third-party tutorials, so you can look up how to translate the code to the newer syntax. The [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) is a good way to get started with that too.

Comment: This is the one I'm looking for! You are a lifesaver. Thanks!

Comment: Any way to get the "Timestamp" type, like we were able to in v8 via firebase.firestore.Timestamp?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp?

Comment: thanks, just found it: import {  Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';